# Pact + Angular Error: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, pact

Using Pact with Angular.

Getting the following error while running tests.
Error: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.

```
    Missing requests:
            GET /dogs
```

Code under test: dog.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DogService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getDogs(baseUrl: string): Observable<Dog[]>{
    return this.http.get<Dog[]>(baseUrl + '/dogs');
  }
}
```

Spec file:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {PactWeb, Matchers} from '@pact-foundation/pact-web';
import { DogService } from './dog.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {Pact} from '@pact-foundation/pact';

describe('Dog service contract tests', () => {
  let provider: PactWeb;


  let dogService: DogService;

  beforeAll(async (done) => {
        provider = new PactWeb({
            port: 1234,
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            log: '.\\log\\pact.log',
            logLevel: 'warn',
            dir: '.\\pacts',
            spec: 2
        });
          // required for slower CI environments
        setTimeout(done, 2000);

          // Required if run with `singleRun: false`
        await provider.removeInteractions();

        console.log('Pact web creation');
    });

  afterEach(async () => {
        await provider.verify();
        console.log('Verify');
    });

  afterAll(async () => {
        return await provider.finalize();
        console.log('Finalize');
    });

  beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
              DogService
            ]
          });
        console.log('Configure test module');
    });

  describe('Contract tests', () => {

      beforeAll(async () => {
        // set up Pact interactions
        await provider.addInteraction({
          state: 'dogs exist',
          uponReceiving: 'get all dogs',
          withRequest: {
              method: 'GET',
              path: '/dogs'
          },
          willRespondWith: {
              status: 200,
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
              },
              body: Matchers.eachLike({
                  avatar: Matchers.like('xyz'),
                  title: Matchers.like('German Shepard'),
                  subTitle: Matchers.like('This is German Shepard'),
                  imageUrl: Matchers.like('xyz'),
                  description: 'Lorem ipsum'

              }, {min: 2}),
          },
      });
        console.log('Add interaction');
      });

      it('Dog details exist', async () => {
        dogService = TestBed.inject(DogService);
        console.log(provider.mockService.baseUrl);
        dogService.getDogs(provider.mockService.baseUrl).subscribe((response) => {
            expect(response).toBeDefined();
            console.log(response);
          });

    });
    });
});
```

What could be the problem??

Package.json:
    "@pact-foundation/karma-pact": "^2.3.1",
    "@pact-foundation/pact": "^9.11.0",
    "@pact-foundation/pact-node": "^10.9.4",
    "@pact-foundation/pact-web": "^9.11.0",

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that it never received that HTTP call, so that's the main giveaway here.

Your call to getDogs is a promise and yet you're not returning it or awaiting it, so it's likely the call is never made.

My guess is that you need to handle the promise correctly so that the test doesn't exit before the call is made.